I can't do one or I can't do it?
Which is correct?

Please do a British accent!
I can't do it.
Please do a British accent!
I can't do one.


After several failed attempts - I can't do it. But if I already know how bad my fake British accent is - I can't do one.

Compare this question on do it vs do that, and do so vs do it.

As general guidance, the referent of "it" in "I can't do it" would be "the action of doing a British Accent" and the referent of "one" would be "a British accent". (one = ".one of them")

So they're both correct, they just have slightly different meanings.
